# What frameworks are there to identify a correlation or reject one?

Tags: correlation, data-visualization, dataset

Have a look at the three graphs presented in exam question 6 on [this paper](http://pmt.physicsandmathstutor.com/download/Biology/A-level/Past-Papers/Edexcel-IAL/Unit-4/January%202012%20QP%20-%20Unit%204%20Edexcel%20Biology%20A-level.pdf) (just the graphs):

[image]

I want to use that as an example for the catastrophe that I am stuck in as a high school student who hasn't delved much into data analysis:

**How am I supposed to deduce a correlation?**

The framework that I am using right now is to look for an overall change between two points and then say that the graphs are correlated within that interval. But then again, at first site, I wouldn't be able to tell that temperature is not correlated with NPP. I mean, there are fluctuations, but usually when reading graphs we tend to ignore the fluctuations. I have no idea why fluctuations are usually ignored, unless it's a physics experiment where they just want to throw it on experimental error.

The case is even worst with a question like the third one, on the same paper. There are great fluctuations and, while not having been taught the specifics of graph analysis, I find it difficult to know what should be ignored and what shouldn't be, when I read graphs.

[image]

Comment: That is a quite long paper! Can you cut out the graph(s) your question is about and include it in your post?  We prefer that questions be self-contained, it should not be necessary to follow links to understand a question.

Comment: I don't know how to.

Comment: Under your post there is an edit tag. Tap that, put the cursor where the graphics file should be, above there is s small menu, use the include pictire icon. Work about as in facebook

Comment: I added the images -- I think there is a minimum rep needed that prevents new members from adding images.

Comment: I guess you've overthinking this. For those unfamiliar with the set-up here, I take it that these are British A level exams, taken in secondary school at age 17 or 18 or so. What I am seeing in the first few graphs is a seasonal pattern of sunlight and temperature (as forcing factors) and NPP (as response). I expect you're just asked to comment on whether the peaks coincide (they don't quite and there is biology there too). Measurement error is not germane to the question, I suspect. There are small measurement issues of different kinds, but the response to seasonal rhythms seems central.

Comment: You seem smart enough to work this through regardless of whether you have been taught much about how to do it. The deficiencies of British secondary school education are off-topic here, but the generalities of look for patterns, look for details that might be informative, check for exceptions or complications are hard to teach except through example after example. Exam boards have no incentive to set trick questions as they too are judged by their results.

Comment: Nick Cox, that is the plan for now, but may you please elaborate further?